# How can i assign a value to a variable which is async in nature

Tags: typescript, appium

I have a typescript based Appium automation framework. Here the element locator strategy is async in nature since the plugin I use is async in nature.(Need to use await). In the below code, I want to use the settings _button value in the methods. but I cannot since I get the error

Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

findElementByText should return a promise. This is what Visual code says,(method) AppiumDriver.findElementByText(text: string, match?: SearchOptions, waitForElement?: number): Promise

```
export class HomeScreen extends BasePage {

settings_button = this._driver.findElementByText('Settings',10);

async isDisplayedSettings(){
    await (await this.settings_button).isDisplayed();
}

async openSettings(){
    await (await this.settings_button).click();

}

}
```

This is used in the mocha test framework something like this.

```
describe("Firmware Update", () => {

let scanDevices: ScanDevices, genFunc: GenericFunctions, settings: SettingsScreen, homeScreen: HomeScreen;

const defaultWaitTime = 5000;
let driver: AppiumDriver;

before(async () => {
    driver = await createDriver();
    scanDevices = new ScanDevices(driver);
    homeScreen = new HomeScreen(driver);
    settings = new SettingsScreen(driver);
    genFunc = new GenericFunctions();
    await genFunc.timeDelay(10000); //Delay for the headset scan
    await scanDevices.clickHeadset();
});

after(async () => {
    await driver.quit();
    console.log("Quit driver!");
});


afterEach(async function () {
    if (this.currentTest.state === "failed") {
        await driver.logScreenshot(this.currentTest.title);
    }
});

it("should display settings option", async () => {
    assert.isTrue(await homeScreen.isDisplayedSettings(),"Option should be displayed");

});

it("should tap settings option", async () => {
    await homeScreen.openSettings();
    assert.isTrue(await settings.isDisplayeUpdatebutton(),"Expecting Settings screen to open");    

});
```

Comment: how are `openSettings` and `isDisplayedSettings` called, you handle errors there ?

Comment: Hi Titian, I've updated the usage part in the description. The thing is I don't want to have the element locator strategy in the methods. If I have to use the same element 5-6 times in that file, I then have to use the locator strategy 5-6 times. So I want to have the element declaration only once

Comment: Please check the bundled Mocha version, I am afraid you are using a version where at least one of the `after`, `before`, `afterEach`, `it` functions does not handle promises at all.

Comment: The same code works if I have the element declaration in the method, something like this const settings_button = await this._driver.findElementbyText('Settings',10) since that method is an async function. But I just want to decouple the locator strategy from the method

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the promise that shows that warning is the one stored in the `settings_button` variable.

The problem is if somebody creates a `HomeScreen` instance, but calls no method on that instance at all, the possible
error in `settings_button` will never be consumed, which is decided to be a fatal error by the nodejs team. There is
just no way in the constructor to ensure that one of those methods will be called in the future.

In your case, the `settings_button` promise always resolves before `isDisplayedSettings` is called, because of the
delay in the `before` block.

You will have to restructure the code. There are two possible ways to resolve this:

- Await the element query in the initialization method. There are no async counstructors so you will need an async
  factory for this instead. I personally prefer this solution.
- Defer the element query until first use. This is semantically the same as your current code, but prevents the unhandled error problem when there are no methods called.

With pseudocode:

Solution 1:

```
export class HomeScreen extends BasePage {
    settings_button : UIElement? = null;
    async init() {
        settings_button = await this._driver.findElementByText('Settings', 10);
    }
    static async create(driver) {
        const result = new HomeScreen(driver);
        await result.init();
        return result;
    }

    // ...
}

// ...

before(async() => {
    // ...
    homeScreen = await HomeScreen.create(driver);
    // ...
});
```

Solution 2:

```
export class HomeScreen extends BasePage {
    _settingsButtonPromise : Promise<UIElement>? = null;
    async getSettingsButton() {
        if (!this._settingsButtonPromise) {
            this._settingsButtonPromise = this._driver.findElementByText('Settings', 10);
        }
        return await this._settingsButtonPromise;
    }

    async isDisplayedSettings(){
        return await (await this.getSettingsButton()).isDisplayed();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Tamas, thanks a lot for your response. Second solution seems to work fine with a slight modification. I just need to remove the type declaration (UIElement) otherwise it results in an error Type 'Promise<UIElement>' is not assignable to type 'UIElement'.
  Property '_element' is missing in type 'Promise<UIElement>'.

Just one question though. If I have like 20-25 elements in a page, I then need to have different async functions for each of the element. Would solution2 still be the best approach in this scenario?

Thanks